# Adding button in pdf using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add a button in Pdf using iTextSharp, and when the button is clicked I want to call a service with the modified data. I am able to add radiobuttons but not able to add the Button. Code what I a using is:

```
public static String[] LANGUAGES_gc = { "English", "German", "Spanish" };
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("GetPdf")]
    public void DownloadPDF()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Example.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        string pdfFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".") + "/PDFFiles";
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        doc.Open();
        doc.AddAuthor("Test author");
        doc.AddCreationDate();
        PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;
        Font _bf = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 6);
        PdfFormField _radioGroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(wri, true);
        _radioGroup.FieldName = "language_gc";
        Rectangle _rect;
        RadioCheckField _radioG;
        PdfFormField _radioField1;
        for (int i = 0; i < LANGUAGES_gc.Length; i++)
        {
            _rect = new Rectangle(46, 806 - i * 40, 60, 788 - i * 40);
            _radioG = new RadioCheckField(wri, _rect, null, LANGUAGES_gc[i]);
            _radioG.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.8f);
            _radioG.BorderColor = GrayColor.BLACK;
            _radioG.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;
            _radioField1 = _radioG.RadioField;
            _radioGroup.AddKid(_radioField1);              

            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(LANGUAGES_gc[i], new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18)), 70, 790 - i * 40, 0);
        }
        /* Button */
        _rect = new Rectangle(46, 806 * 40, 60, 788 * 40);
        PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(wri, _rect, "button");
        PdfAnnotation widget = button.Field;
        button.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.75f);
        button.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
        button.BorderWidth = 1;
        button.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED;
        button.TextColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
        button.FontSize = 11;
        button.Text = "Button";
        button.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_LEFT_LABEL_RIGHT;
        button.ScaleIcon = PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS;
        button.ProportionalIcon = true;
        button.IconHorizontalAdjustment = 0;
        /*----------------------------------------------------*/
        wri.AddAnnotation(_radioGroup);
        cb = wri.DirectContent;
        doc.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(doc);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong.

Comment: I see `wri.AddAnnotation(_radioGroup);` but I don't see `wri.AddAnnotation(button);` anywhere.

Comment: @vickey What version of iText are you using?

Comment: Hello Bruno, Thanks for the help I am able to resolve it now. Problem was the button size because of which it was not appearing. Can you please tell me how to handle the button click and to align it in bottom left.